# Unable to place the buttons at required positions using tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I tried the below code but the buttons are placed only at the center only,it is not placed according to my required positioning

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

def DT(event):
    print "Decision tree is selected"

button3 = Button(root, text="Decision Tree",font=("Helvetica", 15))
button3.place(x=50,y=220)
button3.pack()
button3.bind('<Button-1>', DT)

root.minsize(width=1300, height=700)
#root.configure(background='lavender')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried running your code and got `NameError: name 'root' is not defined`. Please provide code that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: root = Tk() should be included ,i missed to keep it above but i had it in my work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`button3.pack()` overrides the placement made by `button3.place()`.

Delete the `button3.pack()` line.

Answer (score 2):

You are placing and packing the button. Just use either place or pack.